# will ubuntu 13.04 with gnome work on a dell optiplex GX 260

Tags: gnome, 13.04

I have an old dell optiplex gx 260 and ubuntu 13.04 wont work on it. so im wondering if i get ubuntu 13.04 with gnome will it possibly work?

Answer (score 0):

For future postings when asking about compatibility, please include your hardware specs so that we can determine the best course of action for you to follow. That said..

That Dell is an old system (c. 2002) and I would recommend using an alternate 32-bit distribution such as Lubuntu or Xubuntu that have leaner DE's (Desktop Environments) than Gnome. I might lean towards Xubuntu using the 12.04 LTS release as this will have current security updates available for a few more years; Lubuntu does not offer an LTS version at this time.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite old, according to [the specs](http://www.andovercg.com/datasheets/dell-optiplex-gx260.pdf). Ubuntu with GNOME might not run very well esp. since this machine seems to be limited to 1 GB RAM.

Xubuntu (using XFCE) should work reasonably well.

Comment: mine took 2 gigs of ram and even read it when the BIOS told me of the memory change

Answer (score 0):

For older low specific computers you can try:Xubuntu
 Or try to use different distro like: puppy linux (or) Linux lite.

Linux Lite is free for everyone to use and share, and is suitable for people who are new to Linux or for people who want a liteweight environment that is also fully functional. Linux Lite is also great for reviving that old laptop or desktop you gave up on a few years back.